# fast export unexplained failure

Tags: teradata, informatica, fastexport

I have roughly 14 million records that I am attempting to export from a Teradata table to file using a fast export connection object.

There is no size limit for fast export files on our Linux system, and there is 1.2 TB of available space in the target directory.

The session fails, and gives the following errors:
`READER_2_1_1   FEXP_87011  Process [16022] exited with status [12]`
`SDKS_38200 Partition-level [SOURCE_TABLE_NAME]: Plug-in #305400 failed in deinit()`

I googled the error message, and found this post: 
[Here](http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/informatica-l/cw_prod_node-reader_1_1_1-sdks_38200-partitionlevel-sq_mbr-plugin-305400-failed-in-init-4510884)

I followed the recommendations in the port to delete the .out file in the temp directory, delete the files that were partially filled in the target directory, and drop the error table and delete the log file. This did not fix the issue and the session still fails with the same error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use TPT Export plug-in instead. Also you can try to execute this FastExport using bteq scripts directly on your unix environment.